# Why does setting a default value for an existing column in an ActiveRecord Migration not extend to existing associations on production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

If I add a default value to an existing column through an ActiveRecord Migration, when deploying my changes to production, existing associations are not affected.

I can drop to a rails production console and iterate over every single record and set the value on the new column to false on each record however it's tedious and doesn't scale well.

```rb
class AddDefaultValuesToAFewColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_column :downloads, :is_deleted, :boolean, :default => false
  end
end
```

```rb
create_table "downloads", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "version"
    t.string "comment"
    t.string "contributors"
    t.string "release_date"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "download_url"
    t.boolean "is_deleted", default: false
  end
```

The expected result would be for associations when queried from the rails console to return `false` for is_deleted, rather it returns `nil`. Why is this and what alternative solutions are there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how it works. When you change the column default value, you are configuring the default value for new records, not existing ones. If you want to update existing values with `false` then do something like `Download.where(is_deleted: nil).update_all(is_deleted: false)` right after the `change_column` line:

```
class AddDefaultValuesToAFewColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_column :downloads, :is_deleted, :boolean, :default => false
    Download.where(is_deleted: nil).update_all(is_deleted: false)
  end
end
```

Comment: To add to @arieljoud 's comment, you often don't want your columns to automatically update. This is particularly true for scale. DDL statements are locking, and changing values in a column could take a really long time. This would block all other transactions until the updates are complete. Shoot for zero downtime deployments with proper feature enabling, with very fast schema migrations, then back-fill the data in manageable batches to avoid performance impact.

Comment: Try to avoid using model classes in your migrations.  See Habit 4 here: https://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2014-11-04-healthy-migration-habits/#habit-4-dont-reference-models